# Trying to locate a photo transfer that was done on my MacBook

Tags: macos

Is there a way to view file transfers for photos that may have gone off my MacBook by the file sharing being open? Or by way of a USB save? I had private photos stolen by a "friend" while using their network. I haven't been able to find anything as of yet and could really use some help!

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3064484?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Welcome to Information Security SE. `I haven't been able to find anything as of yet` -- what have you tried?